# The reputation in a site is not updated in some sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page, linked-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation display bug… Again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148636/reputation-display-bug-again)

I have visible error on [profile in stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426533/sergey), but profiles on other projects (example: [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/13598/sergey)) look correct.

[image: correct reputation score]
[image: incorrect repuation score on project]
[image: it's again]

Comment: @MrLister, in browser? You seriously think that to blame the browser cache? Stupid answer of course, but I see this error since one week ago.

Comment: @Sergey - Did you try clearing your cookies? Logging out of Code Review, and then logging back in?  There's a lot of caching that happens server side due to the high volume of traffic, so maybe this might trigger the recalc on that page.

Comment: @jmort253, yes I did it twice. Just create here for alert )

Comment: It's server side caching. The values should sync up within a day or so