# Problem with Profile - Accounts/reputation data

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page, linked-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The reputation in a site is not updated in some sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133814/the-reputation-in-a-site-is-not-updated-in-some-sites)

I have several accounts on StackExchange. But today I checked my Profile and it seems that Accounts data is invalid for my reputation when looking at my Profile at SO and meta.SO for my Programmers account.

- Here are the screenshots displaying `1` reputation at Programmers:

  > [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsNoI.png]
  >
  > [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GL15.png]
- My Programmers Profile shows correct data, reputation is `101`.  Here is the screenshot:

  > [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rn9Os.png]

**UPDATE:**

- The status is still the same (issue still remains) after 15 or so hours (the database should have refreshed by know if there was refresh; maybe it is every 24 hours but this is just a guess).
- It seems that [other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133814/the-reputation-in-a-site-is-not-updated-in-some-sites) people are reporting the same issue.  What can be noted is that it seems that problem only occurs on SO and meta.SO and that other sites are operating properly.
- (**5 days later**): Problem still remains so it does not look like it is server side database caching (unless it is triggered on weekly basis). Also I subscribed to different set of sites and on all of them I get "Programmers" to have rep of `1` instead of `101` as seen here:
  [image]

On other hand StackExchange is showing proper values:
[image]

- **NEW UPDATE**: Everything is ok now but in order to do that I earned few points on `Programmers` account and now full `105q reputation points is being shown.  So this at least is workaround to resolve this bug.

Comment: First thought: caching issue? Just wait for while for it to even out.

Comment: @Bart hmm I see rep appear on the accounts list pretty fast. Certainly < 4 hours. I'm betting it's specific to the association bonus. I bet if Bo earned or lost rep on Programmers it would appear.

Comment: Do you mean browser cache? This does not seem to be the problem. Tried CTRL+F5 plus different browser. Problem still there.

Comment: No Bart means account creation data related cache, you have just created your profile there before 14 mins. wait for few minutes.

Comment: (5 days later): Problem still remains so it does not look like it is server side database caching (unless it is triggered on weekly basis).

Comment: That is strange indeed. I can't remember it taking this long. Perhaps there is a problem after all.

Comment: "Dirty" solution: Have sufficient number of accounts (+5) that have rep higher then account causing problems and the problem will go away.  The `view more` link will show up and it will redirect to **StackExchange** site that seems to always report correct values.  I am not sure though how would it behave if I had more then `100` rep (without association bonus) on the site that is causing problems.

Comment: - **NEW UPDATE**: Everything is ok now but in order to do that I earned few points on `Programmers` account and now full `105` reputation points is being shown.  So this at least is workaround to resolve this bug.

Comment: Well, if it motivates user participation, let's call it a feature. ;)

Comment: Very cunning feature... :)