# Reputation Hiccup with Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page, linked-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation display bug… Again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148636/reputation-display-bug-again)

When I associated my account from SO with meta, programmers, superuser etc, I got the +100 reputation for the association on all sites.  So logically, this is what I see on meta under my user profile.

> [image: Meta Profile]

Oddly, the other sites show my Meta rep differently (and have for several weeks now).

> [image: Other Profiles]

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

It's hilarious to me, but apparently this post "fixed" the problem.  The upvotes I got changed my reputation which must have updated something in Stack Exchange's back-end to make it work.  I'm not posting this as an answer because I don't know how the problem was fixed.

Comment: 99% it's caching.

Comment: after several weeks?

Comment: @YannisRizos It seems to be fairly persistent though. [At least for this user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134107/problem-with-profile-accounts-reputation-data). See update at the end of the question. Something wrong after all?

Comment: @deltree Did you try a hard refresh?

Comment: I am still having this problem after 5 days:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134107/problem-with-profile-accounts-reputation-data

Comment: @YannisRizos definitely looks like a duplicate, I didn't see that question when posting it.  Also, I cleared my cache and refreshed the page when it was suggested it was caching, so yes, I hard refreshed

Comment: @Bo correction, looks more like a duplicate of Bo's post, not of the post Yannis linked

Comment: @deltree: **NEW UPDATE**: Everything is ok now but in order to do that I earned few points on `Programmers` account and now full `105` reputation points is being shown.  So this at least is workaround to resolve this bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is a frequented issue that never really gets "resolved" by the devs. Like said, it's likely a "hiccup" where the network cache forgets to update for a certain site. It can easily be resolved by completing some action on the target site that affects your reputation in some way, allowing the network to re-update your reputation in the global cache.

This error *usually* only occurs with new accounts and the bonus.

Just to note: The physical site will **always** show the correct reputation in the accounts list.

Comment: thanks for posting this as an answer.  This is the known about the issue, but not really a fix for it.

Comment: I don't think the devs have really shown any interest in fixing this issue. Nor do I see any point in fixing it. Why does it really matter what your account shows as if you haven't done anything there yet?

Comment: This: `99% it's caching. – Yannis Rizos Jun 4 at 13:32`  Because every time a concerned user says something, they're going to get crapped on by several people.  Can you imagine the posts if this becomes a "known bug"  `Known bug, downvoted - John Doe` and new users lose rep and get discouraged about the stackexchange family of sites.  I don't like it.  It should be fixed.