# The points are not updated to all the profiles

Tags: support, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The reputation in a site is not updated in some sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133814/the-reputation-in-a-site-is-not-updated-in-some-sites)

How much time does it take to update the points on all the profiles.  
Example: I got 2 upvotes for a question on Askubuntu.com say 15 minutes ago. The points at the top of my askubuntu page shows the update score. Even When I click on my user profile at the top, the page shows the updated scores. When I click on the other stackexchange siblings accounts of mine, everywhere the scores(points) have been updated. But when I check my stackoverflow.com profile page, It shows the previous score i.e. 10 less than what Askubuntu.com and other shows.


I don't know if its a bug or what?  Some insight into the process should be good.

Comment: It takes 2-3 days for reputation on one site to show correctly on profiles' on other sites.

Comment: @YannisRizos Got it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're not to the point yet where everything syncs and updates everywhere immediately.  This is a big place.

I've typically been waiting at least a day before bringing syncing/update "bugs" to Meta, though, as Yannis comments, it would be best to wait 2-3 days before thinking it's actually a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Daniel