# Flair not updated with badges

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, flair, caching

It's been **four** days since I earned a gold badge (`Fanatic`, of course) and a few other badges on sites where I have 200+ rep.

My global flair hasn't yet been updated to show the proper badges.

[image]

What is the problem? It should have gotten updated within 36 hours, according to the flair page.

#### EDIT

1. There has been some more changes in my rep, and a new site was added to the flair as the rep has gone above 200 on it. So, that has been updated, but yet the gold badge is not seen.
   [image: flair2]
2. There is a discrepancy between the reputations of different child SE sites shown on the profile pages. It is not being updated across all the child sites.

Please check. There seems to be a bug in 'cross site rep/badge update' script and 'flair update' script I guess.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the English. Can you please also comment on the content, if you can?

Comment: Not really. Mine doesn't seem to have the right badge count either (for gold ones anyway). But I don't use it anywhere so I really don't care much.

Comment: Same here. Reputation and badges are OK for SO flair ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1494505.png)), but badges are wrong in global flair ([link](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1617125.png)).

Comment: I suspect this is due to [Nick's answer here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147247/different-account-details-on-different-sub-sites/147276#147276)

Comment: I too came across, the same reading just now. But that seems to be 10 day back activity whose affect seem to still persist and it is not yet completely fixed. Hope it get's fixed quickly.

Comment: See my comment on the answer below. This appears not to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue wasn't just with your flair but with the denormalized network aggregate table it pulls the information from (as opposed to, ya know, hitting every site's database one by one...ouch).

I deployed a fix for this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148636/reputation-display-bug-again/148646#148646), and you'll see that your flair has already updated as a result:

[image: profile for mtk on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Comment: Is this now working correctly? It has been several days since I obtained my first gold badge, and it is still not showing on my flair.

Comment: This appears not to be fixed. I still do not see my gold badge on my flair.

Comment: It has not been a few weeks and my flair is still not showing my (first) gold badge.

Comment: @SabreWolfy - I'm seeing your flair with a gold badge, are you behind a proxy or anything? Some cache *somewhere* is in play here

Comment: Not behind a proxy and noticed the non-updated flair from different computers at different locations. Just cleared browser cache and hard-refreshed my "Flair" page on my network profile -- still only showing 13 silver and 76 bronze.