# Combined flair not updating with gold badge

Tags: support, badges, flair, combined-flair

I have commented on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147761/flair-not-updated-with-badges/149057#149057) answer (comments indicate that my updated combined flair may be visible to others), but my combined flair is still not updating to reflect my first [gold](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/554/sabrewolfy?tab=badges) badge, which I received a few weeks ago. I have cleared my browser cache and cookies, etc. and hard-refreshed the network profile site showing the flair, as well as manually cutting and pasting the JPG URL. It is still not reflecting my badges correctly. The URL is [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/282850.png). What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You earned your badge on [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/554/sabrewolfy), where you have 195 reputation points.

The flair image only shows badges for sites where you have at least 200 points, so dba.stackexchange.com is not (yet) included in your flair.

As noted on the [flair page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/554/sabrewolfy/flair):

> (please note that only sites where you have more than **200** reputation will appear, and that flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours.)

Just another 5 points more and it'll show up!

As a consolation price, here is the flair image for *just* dba, as of the time of this answer:

[image: SabreWolfy DBA flair]

Comment: Damn, you're too fast. When are you sleeping?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Sleeping, what's that?

Comment: I was afraid you'd be another one of those.

Comment: Yes, I see that note on the flair page -- right above the code I copied and pasted. Can't believe I missed it. Thanks :)

Comment: Yay -- there is my first gold badge ;)

Comment: May it be the first of many, congrats!