# SEDE throws a "network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server" error

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Running any query on SEDE fails, with this message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)

Comment: Happens for me too.

Comment: Maybe [the data's getting updated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/when-will-data-se-get-updated-data/145732#145732) now the [databases have been moved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147247/different-account-details-on-different-sub-sites/147276#147276)?

Comment: Seems something similar happened to me as well. When I'm logged in and try to get to any of my saved queries I get after a long time period an [unspecified runtime error](http://i.imgur.com/8xhX3.jpg).

Comment: @TLama Yep, same problem. It's timing out connecting to the site database while trying to guess your user ID. Could probably catch the exception there, but it's not very expected that the databases completely disappear...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a firewall issue as a result of our weekend maintenance in Oregon.  It should be working now.